# Global file access from anywhere in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular5

In my angular 4 project I have a made a file of some constants and getting access to it I am importing that file to my services  file and can access the variables, but the problem is in each and every services I have to import that file.

Is there any process  so that I can load my constant file in one place and can use that file variables throughout the module not importing it each and every time.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your code? You can export it as a single variable instead of multiple files so that you will only import one file for any variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is **NO**. But you can export as a single variable and access it as,

You can do something like this:

In your config.ts:

```
export const Keys = {
    CONFIG_1: 'VALUE',
    CONFIG_2: 'VALUE'
};
```

Then in the file that you importing it you can do below:

```
import { Keys } from './config';
Keys.CONFIG_1 //return the value 'value'
```

You should always import the file. But if you still wanna do that you can do it in the ugliest way like this:

**`window.globalvar = "myapi"`**